# does not exist in current context c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Got this from the example section of a site which sells components to be able to work with excel files

i copy pasted it into visual studio 2013 and i keep getting this error ...

"Color" does not exist in current context...

ive been reading about these error across the web but some have gave solutions but no
key answer as to the "why" this error exists

something to do about variable being declared inside or outside of the method as like many on this site i am venturing the path of newb

thanks for any help

the link is here is your interested

http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/SampleExplorer/Spreadsheet/BasicFeatures/StylesandFormatting?tab=cs

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using GemBox.Spreadsheet;

class Sample
{
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // If using Professional version, put your serial key below.
    SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");

    ExcelFile ef = new ExcelFile();
    ExcelWorksheet ws = ef.Worksheets.Add("Styles and Formatting");

    ws.Cells[0, 1].Value = "Cell style examples:";
    ws.PrintOptions.PrintGridlines = true;

    int row = 0;

    // Column width of 4, 30 and 35 characters.
    ws.Columns[0].Width = 4 * 256;
    ws.Columns[1].Width = 30 * 256;
    ws.Columns[2].Width = 35 * 256;

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.Borders.SetBorders(...)";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.Borders.SetBorders(MultipleBorders.All, Color.FromArgb(252, 1, 1), LineStyle.Thin);

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.FillPattern.SetPattern(...)";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.FillPattern.SetPattern(FillPatternStyle.ThinHorizontalCrosshatch, Color.Green, Color.Yellow);

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.Font.Color =";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "Color.Blue";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.Font.Color = Color.Blue;

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.Font.Italic =";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "true";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.Font.Italic = true;

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.Font.Name =";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "Comic Sans MS";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.Font.Name = "Comic Sans MS";

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.Font.ScriptPosition =";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "ScriptPosition.Superscript";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.Font.ScriptPosition = ScriptPosition.Superscript;

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.Font.Size =";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "18 * 20";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.Font.Size = 18 * 20;

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.Font.Strikeout =";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "true";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.Font.Strikeout = true;

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.Font.UnderlineStyle =";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "UnderlineStyle.Double";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.Font.UnderlineStyle = UnderlineStyle.Double;

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.Font.Weight =";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "ExcelFont.BoldWeight";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.Font.Weight = ExcelFont.BoldWeight;

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.HorizontalAlignment =";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "HorizontalAlignmentStyle.Center";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignmentStyle.Center;

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.Indent";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "five";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignmentStyle.Left;
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.Indent = 5;

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.IsTextVertical = ";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "true";
    // Set row height to 50 points.
    ws.Rows[row].Height = 50 * 20;
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.IsTextVertical = true;

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.NumberFormat";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = 1234;
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.NumberFormat = "#.##0,00 [$Krakozhian Money Units]";

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.Rotation";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "35 degrees up";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.Rotation = 35;

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.ShrinkToFit";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "This property is set to true so this text appears shrunk.";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.ShrinkToFit = true;

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.VerticalAlignment =";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "VerticalAlignmentStyle.Top";
    // Set row height to 30 points.
    ws.Rows[row].Height = 30 * 20;
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignmentStyle.Top;

    ws.Cells[row += 2, 1].Value = ".Style.WrapText";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Value = "This property is set to true so this text appears broken   into multiple lines.";
    ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.WrapText = true;

    ef.Save("Styles and Formatting.xls");
 }
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding `using System.Drawing.Color;` in addition to `using System.Drawing;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are referencing the `System.Drawing` dll under References in the Solution Explorer.

Any .NET class is documented in MSDN, and every time you will see both the namespace AND the assembly in which it "lives".

The Assembly has to be added under `References` in the `Solution Explorer`, and the namespace must be added to your code with a `using` directive.

For example, here's a snapshot of the Color class from MSDN:

[image]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

[Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) resides in `System.Drawing` namespace in `System.Drawing.dll` assembly. Therefore, in addition to have using statement :

```
using System.Drawing;
```

you need to add reference to `System.Drawing` assembly. It isn't referenced by default in console project template.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-modest-proposal-for-the-copy-and-paste-school-of-code-reuse/).  :)

Maybe you are copying the example there but not referencing `GemBox.Spreadsheet`. 
If you want to use [this](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/free-version) you should add this as reference.